# make all possible combinations in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, combinations

I want to make all possible combination from my elements in an array, and I have no clue how to do this, just a little smart.

my array looks like this:

> @array = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

and I wish to get an output like this:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdf
abce
abcef
...

etc
```

with all combinations, no overlapping (e.g. ab and ba). and having any number of elements from 1-6. The order doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

See [Math::Subsets::List](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aSubsets%3a%3aList):

```
use Math::Subsets::List;
subsets {say "@_"} qw(a b c);
#
#  a
#  b
#  c
#  a b
#  a c
#  b c
#  a b c
```

Comment: Sorry, im a newbie in this, do I need to install anything to use this?

Comment: I think the user want to get the algorithms of the problem, not only use the module to achieve it.

Comment: it doesnt matter if it is the algorithm or a module (which im not sure how to use) but I work on a server, where im not allowed to install anything.

Comment: @JackXu: The source code is available at the linked page at a 1 click distance.

Comment: I get this error: syntax error at file.pl line 20, near "say"@_""
Illegal declaration of subroutine main::subsets at ./file.pl line 22.

Comment: the source code is hard to understand... The variable names is hard to understand...

Comment: So close now, can anyone help. What exactly do I need to type to use this module?

Answer (score 1):

[Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) module does exactly what you want:

[Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm) module does it too.

Comment: I did already look at Math::Combinatorics. But as far as I can see, it only makes an output including all elements (e.g. abcdef) and not for instance abc

Answer (score 0):

So you want

```
for my $s0 ($array[0], '') {
   for my $s1 ($array[1], '') {
      for my $s2 ($array[2], '') {
         ...
            print(join('', $s1, $s2, $s3, ...), "\n");
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Use [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aLoops)'s `NestedLoops` when you want arbitrarily nested loops.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

NestedLoops(
   [ map { $_, "" } @array ],
   sub { print(join('', @_), "\n"); },
);
```

But you might notice each of those loops have two states. Binary! It can be done with little overheard.

```
my $num_bits = @array;
my $last = ~( -1 << $num_bits );
my $high_bit_mask = 1 << ( $num_bits - 1 );

for (my $i = $last; $i--; ) {
   my $s = '';
   my $mask = $high_bit_mask;
   for my $bit_num (0..$num_bits) {
      $s .= $array[$bit_num] if $i & $mask;
      $mask >>= 1;
   }

   print("$s\n");
}
```